# Brave browser msal.js Azure AD login_required: AADSTS50058 not refreshing

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I have a React frontend Using MSAL.js with the Auth code flow + PKCE to provide Authentication against AzureAD. When using a current version of chrome it seems to refresh tokens after expiry without an issue. However Brave browser fails to refresh and causes an error when the iframe is triggered.

[image: iframe triggered for refresh]

```
Uncaught (in promise) InteractionRequiredAuthError: login_required: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
```

Reading into this chrome will implement strict cookie handling in 2024. Is MS Azure team working on this?

Can someone help with an example of how they are handling and resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error ,when the account is logged in with two mails
login_required:

```
AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
```

In that case , try to send account  id in login hint, for the browser to recognize exact  account session

*Ex: login_hint: xxx@company.com',*

```
  const silentRequest = {
        scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.Read"],
        loginHint: "user@contoso.com"
        domainHint: "preferred_tenant_id"  // in case of multitenants
    };

   try {
    const loginResponse = await msalInstance.ssoSilent(silentRequest);
       } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(silentRequest).catch(error => {
            // handle error
        });
    } else {
        // handle error
    }

 }
```

And try disable the following option in browser setting:

```
third party cookies
```

[image]

And add `https://login.microsoft.com` to the whitelisted sites

[image]

And then try again.

**Reference :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#third-party-cookies

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will give this a go after the holidays.  This will be great for testing but my users would likely not do this.  It is fair to see we are waiting for Microsoft to change how Azure works and move away from iframes given all browsers will soon block these cookies?